# Can PySpark work with numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I tried to execute the following commands in a pyspark session:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> da = sc.parallelize(a)
>>> da.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

It worked fine. I got the expected answer (which is 55). Now I try to do the same but using numpy arrays instead of Python lists:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
>>> da = sc.parallelize(a)
>>> da.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

As a result I get a lot of errors. To be more specific, I see the following error several times in the error message:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy.core.multiarray
```

Is something not install not my cluster or pyspark is not able to work with numpy array on a fundamental level?

Comment: It looks like a configuration (version mismatch?) problem otherwise should work just fine.

Comment: it says here that numpy is supported: [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#linking-with-spark) It gives some info under the tab Python.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. I did below and issue resolved:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
pip install nose
```