# Image in the form of Numpy array in a cell in Pyspark data frame

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to store a image represented as a numpy array in a Pyspark data frame. 
When I try the I get an error data type not supported.

looking at the data types supported in Pyspark I don't see numpy, wondering if there's a way to store array.

I also tried numpy as string but the string for some reason is truncated contains ...

Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045386/

Comment: You can use spark matrix / vector UDT but I won't be efficient anyway.